How to import a component only in a certain component asynchronously
How do I import a component only in a certain component asynchronously?
I need a separate chunk with graphs.
createCharts() {
    const chartElements = document.querySelectorAll('[apexChartWrapper]');
    if (!chartElements?.length) {
        return;
    }

    const VueApexCharts = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./v-apex-charts.vue'));

    for (let chart of chartElements) {
        let app = createApp({
            mounted() {
                this.$el.parentNode.replaceWith(this.$el);
            }
        });
        app.use(VueApexCharts);
        app.component('v-apexchart', VueApexCharts);

        app.mount(chart);
    }
},


I believe you would need to use <Suspense /> and add the :key attribute to the component you are awaiting.
